# Cannot write an instance of play.api.libs.json.JsLookupResult to HTTP response. Try to define a Writable[play.api.libs.json.JsLookupResult]

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, playframework, sbt

I am upgrading Play Framework server from 2.2.2 to 2.4.4, as my application is working fine with old version, but while upgrading it is giving various errors like:

```
 Cannot write an instance of play.api.libs.json.JsLookupResult to HTTP response. Try to define a Writable[play.api.libs.json.JsLookupResult]
    Ok<gts<0>>
      ^
```

build.sbt:

```
name := """TestApp"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

//scalaVersion := "2.11.6"
//scalaVersion := "2.10.2"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  jdbc,
  cache,
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "anorm" % "2.4.0",
  "com.google.inject" % "guice" % "4.0",
  "javax.inject" % "javax.inject" % "1",
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "reactivemongo" % "0.10.0",
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.10.2",
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "1.9.5" % "test",
  "org.webjars" % "requirejs" % "2.1.1",
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1200-jdbc41",
  "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901.jdbc4",
  "com.typesafe.play" % "play-iteratees_2.10" % "2.2.3",
  "com.typesafe.slick" % "slick_2.10" % "2.1.0",
  "com.typesafe.play" % "play-jdbc_2.10" % "2.4.4",
  "org.apache.flume" % "flume-ng-core" % "1.5.2",
  "org.apache.flume" % "flume-ng-sdk" % "1.5.2",
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % "2.11.6"
)
```

app.scala:

```
package controllers

import play.modules.reactivemongo.MongoController
import play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection.JSONCollection
import scala.concurrent.Future
import reactivemongo.api.Cursor
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import javax.inject.Singleton
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.json._

@Singleton
class Application extends Controller with MongoController {

  def collection: JSONCollection = db.collection[JSONCollection]("Test")

  import models._
  import models.JsonFormats._
  import reactivemongo.bson._

  def index = Action.async {
    val cursor: Cursor[JsValue] = collection.
      find(Json.obj()).
      cursor[JsValue]
    val futureUsersList: Future[List[JsValue]] = cursor.collect[List]()
    val futurePersonsJsonArray: Future[JsArray] = futureUsersList.map { dao =>
      Json.arr(dao)
    }

    futurePersonsJsonArray.map {
      dao =>
        Ok(dao(0))
    }
  }

}
```

Please let me know where I am doing wrong whether it is in my controller class or build.sbt ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Indexing a `JsArray` does not return the `JsValue` at that index but a `JsLookupResult`, which is either `JsDefined` or `JsUndefined` (if, e.g, the index is out-of-bounds.) I *think* this changed in Play 2.3.

While you can write a `JsValue` directly to an HTTP response via the default JSON writeable provided by Play, there is no such writeable for a `JsLookupResult`. You can fix it by pattern matching on the `JsLookupResult` to extract the value, and handle its absence:

```
futurePersonsJsonArray.map { dao =>
  dao(0).match {
    case JsDefined(js) => Ok(js)
    case _ => NotFound
  }
}
```

or use `toOption` to get an `Option[JsValue]`:

```
futurePersonsJsonArray.map { dao =>
  dao(0).toOption.map(js => Ok(js)).getOrElse(NotFound)
}
```

**However**, a better way to fix the code would be to use `Json.toJson()` directly on the redeemed result of `futureUserList`, rather than putting it in a JSON array, and then immediately taking it out again:

```
def index = Action.async {
  val cursor: Cursor[JsValue] = collection.
    find(Json.obj()).
    cursor[JsValue]
  val futureUsersList: Future[List[JsValue]] = cursor.collect[List]()

  futureUsersList.map { list =>
    Ok(Json.toJson(list))
  }
}
```